# How to make this popup responsive with different screen size

Tags: html, css

I am making a popup message with css and html. I am trying to make the popup layout more responsive but with limited css knowledge I am stuck. Basically I don't want to force the `div` with fixed pixels as much as possible. Also, my `Button` and `Anchor url` are also hardcoded with fix location in CSS. How can I improve that?

When the popup display, I want to greyout the page behind it. But, it seems to work in jsfiddle but when I put it to my web page I only see half of the page is grey out when the popup display. How can I make the full page to grey out?

Please see here: http://jsfiddle.net/chs9x9wj/274/

Popup will looks like this:

[image]

css:

```
div.outer {
    position: relative;
    width: 300px;
    height: 270px;
    border: 3px solid black;
    text-align: center;
    margin:auto;
    z-index: 100;
    background-color: yellow;
} 
div.outer a {
    color: blue;
} 
div.inner-right {
    position: absolute;
    top: 80px;
    right: 10px;
    width: 240px;
    height: 100px;
    /*border: 3px solid blue;*/
    text-align: left;
}

div.inner-left {
    position: absolute;
    top: 80px;
    left: 10px;
    width: 20px;
    height: 100px;
    /*border: 3px solid red;*/
    color: red;
}

div.inner-buttom {
    position: absolute;
    top: 180px;
    left: 120px;
    text-align: center;
}

.prompt-backdrop {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background: black;
    opacity: .8;
    z-index: 99;

}
```

Html:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Show me the Pop Up</button>

<div class="prompt-backdrop" id="backdrop" style="visibility: hidden"></div>

<br/>

  <div class="outer" id="myPopup" style="visibility: hidden">

      <a>!</a>
      <br/><br/>

      <a>This div element has position: relative</a>
      <div class="inner-right">
        This is a fact: <br/> <br/>
        The human eye can distinguish about 10 million different colors.
      </div>
      <div class="inner-left">
          !
      </div>

      <div class="inner-buttom">
            <input type="submit" class="like" value="Next" />
            <p><a href="google.com">Go Back</a></p>
      </div>
  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

JavaScript:

```
function myFunction() {

  document.getElementById("myPopup").style.visibility = "visible";
      document.getElementById("backdrop").style.visibility = "visible";
}
```

Comment: [Media queries](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_mediaqueries_ex.asp)

Answer (score 0):

Using `max-width` in your CSS is an easy way to dynamically scale elements when the screen gets smaller without using media queries.

If you want to keep your bottom links centered, you can define a width, ex. `width: 100px;`, set `left: 50%;` to move the element halfway across the parent, then `margin-left: -50px;` (or negative half the value of whatever your width is) in order to center it.

Here's a fiddle with a few of those changes made to help get you started:
http://jsfiddle.net/chs9x9wj/281/

Answer (score 0):

I removed some of the absolutes, floated & padded the left & right inner divs and allowed the button to cascade.

The background of "grey" depends on a light background behind it to show through the 99% opacity, maybe the background that is not becoming grey has a darker background.

**css:**

```
div.outer {
    -ms-transform: translate(0px, 50%); /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform: translate(0px, 50%); /* Safari */
    transform: translate(0px, 50%);
    position: relative;
    width: 300px;
    height: 270px;
    border: 3px solid black;
    text-align: center;
    margin: auto;
    z-index: 100;
    background-color: yellow;
} 
div.outer a {
    color: blue;
} 
div.inner-right {
    padding-right: 10px;
    float: right;
    width: 240px;
    height: 100px;
    text-align: left;
}

div.inner-left {
    padding-left: 5px;
    float: left;
    width: 20px;
    height: 100px;
    color: red;
}

div.inner-button {
    text-align: center;
}

.prompt-backdrop {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background: black;
    opacity: .8;
    z-index: 99;

}
```

**html:**

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<body>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Show me the Pop Up</button>

<div class="prompt-backdrop" id="backdrop" style="visibility: hidden"></div>

<br/>

  <div class="outer" id="myPopup" style="visibility: hidden">

      <a>!</a>
      <br><br>
      <a>This div element has position: relative</a>
      <br><br>
      <div class="inner-right">
        This is a fact: <br/> <br/>
        The human eye can distinguish about 10 million different colors.
      </div>
      <div class="inner-left">
          !
      </div>
      <div class="inner-button">
            <input type="submit" class="like" value="Next" />
            <p><a href="https://www.google.com">Go Back</a></p>
      </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**js: *unchanged***

[image of the test popup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/INAho.png)

Comment: How do I make the popup to be center of the screen? vertical center and horizontal center.

Comment: /*added to div.outer*/
-ms-transform: translate(0px, 50%); /* IE 9 */
-webkit-transform: translate(0px, 50%); /* Safari */
transform: translate(0px, 50%);

Comment: I tested that on my app and it seems to center the popup on the page and not the screen. i.e The height of my page is longer than the screen's height and your code puts the popup at the middle of the page instead of the screen.

Comment: I do get what you mean, half way down the page would not be in the visible window though unless in portrait mode perhaps.
Will the page height be fixed or only in portrait?
or maybe you want to make the popup to appear half way down the page and then essentially scroll halfway down the page to it automatically?

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/9x6v74sb/22/

If you can use Flexbox, I recommand something like that.

You should probably add a

```
document.getElementById("back").onclick = function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    document.getElementById("overlay").className = "";
}
```

Comment: I like this idea. But you have removed the `left` and `top` part of my popup which I also need. How can I include that in your design?

Comment: Updated. For the one on the left, I've put it as a pseudo-element.

Comment: I don't think you have updated the code yet, did you?

Comment: Oops! My bad! Should be ok now!

Comment: No it doesn't look like you saved your code. Can you update again?

Comment: Alright, Sorry, it's not working. SO here what you have to add: 

Add to the first `<p>` the class 'alert'. 

HTML :
(right under the opening "popup" tag)
`<div class="inner-top">!</div>`

CSS:
(anywhere)
`.inner-top {
   position: absolute;
   top: 50px;
   left: 0;
   width: 100%; 
   text-align: center;
}

.alert {position: relative;}

.alert:before {
   position: absolute;
   top: 0;
   left: -20px;
   content: '!';
   color: red;
}`